# Malformed xml returned by personnal webservice

Tags: jquery, ajax, web-services

I am building a webservice.
The server program is written in OCaml using [Ocamlnet](http://projects.camlcity.org/projects/ocamlnet.html) library.

The server delivers html pages (and css/js files), and can also answer to specific requests by sending a json encoded string.

I have a html client interface that makes requests to the server using the jquery ajax requests.

Each time I make a request, I have this error :

```
Erreur d’analyse XML : mal formé
Emplacement : http://localhost:1512/sim_commands/?command=my_command
Numéro de ligne 1, Colonne 1 :
```

Note that whatever the request, location is always

```
line : 1, column : 1
```

Also note that this error doesn't prevent my service from working as expected,
data is received and treated without problem, but, well, things would be nicer if the error wasn't present.

I suspect that my error comes from the way I send and receive the json data, as I know pretty much to nothing about the specifications of web requests.

Here is the function making ajax calls :

```
self.ajax = function(uri, method, data) {
        var request = {
            url: uri,
            dataType: 'json',
            data: data,
            crossDomain: true,
            success : function(json) {
                console.log(json);
            },
            error: function(jqXHR) {
                console.log("ajax error " + jqXHR.status);
            }
        };
        return $.ajax(request);
    }
```

So I'm wondering if there is anything missing client side for handling raw json data, or if there is some specific options server side to deliver this kind of data.

Answer (score 0):

Ok well I finally solved my issue.

The clean way is to set the cgi header before sending data :

```
  cgi # set_header ~content_type:"application/json" ();
  cgi # out_channel # output_string response;
  cgi # out_channel # commit_work();
```

(where "application/json" is expected by the ajax call.

But it is also possible to overwrite it ajax side, using

```
beforeSend: function(xhr){
            if (xhr.overrideMimeType)
            {
                xhr.overrideMimeType("application/json");
            }
        }
```

as an argument in the ajax call.